# Google Drive resumable upload has suddenly stopped working for Google Apps Marketplace App

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

We use a Consumer Key / Key Secret provided by a Google Apps Marketplace App to upload files to Google Drive via resumable upload (doclist api) - this has worked fine for over a year. As of 1st August 2013 uploads fail with a generic 500 error returned. Using the same key / secret  other operations do work such as creating folders in drive etc, resumable uploads however will not work.

We **know** that this issue is down to the key / key secret - in tests we have used the key pair from another of our Marketplace Apps and the same code runs fine.

Have tried regenerating the key secret and still no joy.

Has anyone seen similar behaviour or found a fix for this - it is very strange indeed.

This is an Appengine App - stack trace below:

```
Server responded with: 500, Internal Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 716, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goodocdrop-hrd/70.369239377977712685/handler.py", line 533, in post
    new_entry = uploader.UploadFile('/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false', entry=entry)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goodocdrop-hrd/70.369239377977712685/gdata/client.py", line 1026, in upload_file
    auth_token=auth_token, entry=entry)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goodocdrop-hrd/70.369239377977712685/gdata/client.py", line 944, in _init_session
    http_request=http_request)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goodocdrop-hrd/70.369239377977712685/gdata/client.py", line 320, in request
    RequestError)
RequestError: Server responded with: 500, Internal Error
```

Comment: What is the most effective way to get assistance from Google - we have logged requests at http://support.google.com/a/bin/request.py?&contact_type=apps_marketplace but four days on no response - as far as we can tell the fix is completely out of our hands and we need assistance from Google...

Comment: I have now had a reply back from Google to confirm they are looking into the issue - so for other developers who requires Google's help with a Google Apps Marketplace issue, you need to fill out the form at this link support.google.com/a/bin/… and then wait... it took several days to get a response. – user1384757 4 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced a similar problem.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058829/post-method-for-resumable-media-link-stopped-working

The solution we found was not related to the key and key secret.
We just switched from an HTTP POST method to a PUT method.

Comment: The point at which we get the 500 error returned (using Python & AppEngine) is:         'new_entry = uploader.UploadFile('/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false', entry=entry)' - I don't see any other way to do this - could you post your code change? cheers Ian

Comment: It appears we got the error before that point. We got the error when trying to obtain the link that you passed to the UploadFile method. So the solution I suggested would not apply to your case.